# Report from jasper server is received in response but not downloaded through rest

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement jasper server rest in my angular project. Now I am able to get the report in my response but how to download it using appropriate name and type?

```
public downloadReport()
  {
    this.jasperServer.getReport('reports/reports/My_Samples/WasiatGroup.pdf').subscribe((response:any)=>{
      //report is recieved in response but how to download it with appropriate name and type?
    })
  }
```

[image: response image]

if I change the file type to html in request. I received html file in response which looks good in preview my only problem is I don't know how to download these files to their respective formats(pdf,xls,xlsx etc).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turn out you can do it in only 3 lines of code inside function. Just make sure that the response type of http request is arraybuffer

```
public downloadReport()
  {
    this.jasperServer.getReport('reports/reports/My_Samples/WasiatGroup.pdf').subscribe((response:any)=>{
      const blob = new Blob([response],{'type':'application/pdf'})
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.open(url);
      
    })
  }
```